# Find the equation of a parabola (in general form)

Tags: analytic-geometry

Find the equation of the parabola with axis parallel to the $y$-axis, passing through $(1/2,-5/2),(3/2,-9/4)$ and $(-7/2,3/2)$.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find the equation of the parabola](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/250919/find-the-equation-of-the-parabola)

Comment: This is not a duplicate . the idea is different although this also deals with finding equation of parabola

Comment: What is the "axis" of a parabola?  Is this a common term?

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
\begin{align}
{\rm y}\pars{x}&=
A\pars{x - \half}\pars{x - {3 \over 2}}
+B\pars{x - {3 \over 2}}\pars{x + {7 \over 2}}
+C\pars{x - \half}\pars{x + {7 \over 2}}
\end{align}

> In order to determine $\ds{A, B , C}$ use 
>   $$
> {\rm y}\pars{-\,{7 \over 2}} = {3 \over 2}\,,\qquad
> {\rm y}\pars{\half} = -\,{5 \over 2}\,,\qquad
> {\rm y}\pars{3 \over 2} = -\,{9 \over 4}
> $$

Answer (score 0):

HINT:(Idea behind the problem) **A parabola is a graph of a quadratic function**

$$ \displaystyle\boxed{y =ax^2 + bx + c}$$

substitute 3 points given , you will get 3 equations in a,b,c and from there  find a  , b , c solving the 3 equations .and then substitute this a,b,c in the equation above and that will be your answer .

refer : [parabola with axis paraller to y axis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola#Dimensions_of_parabolas_with_axes_of_symmetry_parallel_to_the_y-axis)

refer an example : [refer in case you have doubts and want example](http://www.algebra.com/algebra/homework/quadratic/Quadratic_Equations.faq.question.112182.html)

solution from wolfram alpha : [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=parabola%20through%20%281/2,%E2%88%925/2%29,%20%283/2,%E2%88%929/4%29,%20%28%E2%88%927/2,3/2%29.)

Comment: Your parabola has axis parallel to the $x$-axis.

Comment: No . this is only for axis parallel to y axis . see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Quadratic_function.png

Comment: oh, is it different from x^2 +dx + ey + f = 0?

Comment: My bad, I thought by axis you meant directrix.

Comment: @mona I didn't get what you are asking in comment 3.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is a good shortcut, but by convention it's as follows:

With axis parallel to the y axis, if the vertex of the  parabola is on the origin, then the equation is $x^2=4ay$. But when you shift the parabola on a vertex with coordinates $(h,k)$, the equation becomes $(x-h)^2=4a(y-k)$. Substitute the values you gave to find h,k and a (three equations, three unknowns).

But I would also recommend going by $y=ax^2+bx+c$, since the convention might get messy.

Comment: Using the standard form for the equation of the parabola doesn't create as much trouble as you might think, since the $ \ 4ak \ $ term will cancel between any pair of equations, reducing them to having two unknowns, $ \ a \ $ and $ \ h \ $ . You can then go back and pick up $ \ k \ $ .

Answer (score -1):

Standard form:   $(x+20)^2 + (y+24)^2 = (\dfrac{185}{2})^2$

General form: $2x^2 + 2y^2 - 20x -24y - 63$